# How to convert data and time to a number of days in python (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column called "dateCreated" and it contains a date and time, and I want to convert it to a number of days.

This is my column
This is the data as a text: 2021-12-20T15:58:33.948Z

[image]

I tried this

```
train_data['dateCreated'] = (train_data['dateCreated'] - date.today()).dt.days
```

Comment: you need the day part of the date? also, no images. post the data as a text or preferably as a code  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: posted an answer, does it address your question?

Answer (score 1):

first convert column type to datetime and add a column current date finally get number of days between this two date:

```
from datetime import datetime
df['dateCreated']=pd.to_datetime(df['dateCreated'],format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S:%fZ')
df['today']=pd.to_datetime(datetime.today())
df['days']=(df['today'] - df['dateCreated']).dt.days
```

Answer (score 1):

if you post the data as a code I would be able to share the result

```
df['dateCreated'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dateCreated'])

df['diff']=df['timestamp'].apply(lambda x: (((pd.Timestamp.today()) - x).total_seconds()/(24*3600))  )
df
```

Sample data used

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':['2022-10-01 01:00:00', 
                                 '2022-10-02 01:00:00', 
                                 '2022-10-03 01:00:00', 
                                 '2022-10-04 01:00:00', 
                                 '2022-10-05 01:00:00',
                                 '2022-10-01 02:00:00', 
                                 '2022-10-02 02:00:00', 
                                 '2022-10-03 02:00:00', 
                                 '2022-10-04 02:00:00', 
                                 '2022-10-05 02:00:00']
}
                  )
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df['diff']=df['timestamp'].apply(lambda x: (((pd.Timestamp.today()) - x).total_seconds()/(24*3600))  )
df
```

```
    timestamp   diff
0   2022-10-01 01:00:00     18.610530
1   2022-10-02 01:00:00     17.610530
2   2022-10-03 01:00:00     16.610530
3   2022-10-04 01:00:00     15.610530
4   2022-10-05 01:00:00     14.610530
5   2022-10-01 02:00:00     18.568864
6   2022-10-02 02:00:00     17.568864
7   2022-10-03 02:00:00     16.568864
8   2022-10-04 02:00:00     15.568864
9   2022-10-05 02:00:00     14.568864
```